# Can I use the same passport.js session of one server to log into others

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, single-sign-on, passport.js

I'm using [passport.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) with [express server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and I have the [example repo running](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example) on port 3000.

I want to be able to use port 3000 to login with passport like in the example and have the session created work on two other node servers running on different ports (8000 and 9000). All 3 servers are on localhost.

On one of the other servers I want to have like

```
app.all('*', require('connect-ensure-login')
             .ensureLoggedIn("http://localhost:3000/login"));
```

To make the entire other server only accessible if the user has logged in at localhost:3000.

With my suggested code above if I navigate to http://localhost:8000/somepage it will redirect to http://localhost:3000/login whether I am logged in on 3000 or not. It won't recognise that I have logged in on 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need them to all share the same session store. There are loads of options for the session store; [here is a fairly complete list](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) . The simplest is probably the session-file-store, since it doesn't require you to run any other database or memory-cachinge service. You can configure it to use a specific path to store the sessions in, so that you can make all three server's look in the same place:

```
var session = require( 'express-session' );
var FileStore = require( 'session-file-store' )( session );

app.use( session( {
    store: new FileStore( {
        path: '/path/to/shared/session/storage/directory',
    } ),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
} ) );
```